Crash on launch from all TestFlight builds, but when loading the app from Xcode
We are preparing a launch for iOS 18, and we experienced crashes from iOS 17 devices. If I load the app right from Xcode 16 RC to the iOS 17 device, then it works fine, but if I download it from TestFlight, the nit crashes.
The app crashes immediately upon launch due to a missing symbol in the Foundation framework. I'm hoping someone can provide insights or suggestions on how to resolve this.
Error Message
CopySymbol not found: _$s10Foundation14NSDecimalRoundyySpySo0B0aG_SPyADGSiSo14NSRoundingModeVtF
Referenced from: <C1ABDA48-29EE-3674-8554-669220A76F81> /Volumes/VOLUME/*/CamPlan.app/CamPlan
Expected in: <D92E19C1-6299-3E94-8614-C505D5ABCCDB> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation

What I've Tried
Verified that the app is compiled with the latest Xcode version
Checked for any usage of private APIs (none found)
Reviewed usage of Foundation framework methods, especially those related to NSDecimalRound
Questions
What could be causing this symbol to be missing?
Are there any known issues with NSDecimalRound or related functions in recent iOS versions?
How can I identify which part of my code is trying to use this missing symbol?

Related issue maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78979618/nsdecimalstring-crashes-xcode-16 wait for next RC?

I have the same crash. On TestFlight and when I run my app in release.

In my case it helped to avoid using Decimal in my code.
